# Cannot set PAM_AUTHTOK with pam_set_item

Tags: unix, pam

I am trying to make a simple display manager, therefore I need to authenticate the user so I started to learn how to use PAM. I would like to set the password without a console prompt, so I tried to use `pam_set_item` with `AUTHTOK` but it throws a Bad Item error... Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  struct pam_conv conversation;
  pam_handle_t* pam_handle;
  int status = pam_start("test_pam", "myusername", &conversation, &pam_handle);

  char* password = "mypassword";
  status = pam_set_item(pam_handle, PAM_AUTHTOK, password);
  printf("Error: %s\n", pam_strerror(pam_handle, status));

  status = pam_end(pam_handle, status);
}
```

Do you know how I can send the password to PAM without having to enter it from a console prompt ?

Comment: @elexonics & nonnoursheureux -  did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: `struct pam_conv conversation` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It says:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_set_item

> PAM_AUTHTOK The authentication token (often a password). This token
>   should be ignored by all module functions besides
>   pam_sm_authenticate(3) and pam_sm_chauthtok(3). In the former function
>   it is used to pass the most recent authentication token from one
>   stacked module to another. In the latter function the token is used
>   for another purpose. It contains the currently active authentication
>   token.

So that you cannot set PAM_AUTHTOK unless you are implementing pam_sm_authenticate or pam_sm_chauthtok functions.